# How to deploy a Codeigniter application that contain a NodeJs module to Bluemix?

Tags: node.js, codeigniter, express, socket.io, ibm-cloud

I'm currently working on a codeigniter application with some nodejs for some real time features, i integrated the nodejs module to develop a real time chat application using socket.io and express. I tried to deploy my app to bluemix using a php build for my codeigniter app and i created a nodejs app to host my nodejs server. the problem is i can't seem to connect to the nodejs server socket using io.connect(). is there any way to do so without having to make some major changes in the code.
thanks.

```js
/*eslint-env node*/

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// node.js starter application for Bluemix
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// This application uses express as its web server
// for more info, see: http://expressjs.com
var express = require('express');
//var socket = require('socket.io');

// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

// create a new express server
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));


var people = [];
var left = [];
var connetcted = false;
io.on('connection', function (client) {
    console.log("New client !");
    console.log("socket.id", client.id);

    client.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log('Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message);

        //client.broadcast.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
        io.emit('message', {name: data.name, message: data.message, to: data.to});
    });

    client.on('connected', function (data) {
        console.log('Message received ' + data);
        people[data.current] = data;
        connetcted = true;
        delete left[data.current];
        //client.broadcast.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
        io.emit('connected', {current: data.current, people: people});
        client.on('disconnect', function () {
            connetcted = false;
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (connetcted === false) {
                    left[data.current] = data;
                    delete people[data.current];
                    io.emit('deconnexion', {current: data.current, left: left});
                }
            }, 10000);

        });
    });

    client.on('notification_client', function (data) {
        console.log('Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.id_client);

        //client.broadcast.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
        io.emit('notification_client', {message: data.message, id_client: data.id_client});
    });

    client.on('notification', function (data) {
        console.log('notification received ' + data.event_id);

        //client.broadcast.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
        io.emit('notification', {message: data.message, event_id: data.event_id, id_tenant: data.id_tenant});

        //Pushbots.setMessage(data.message, 1);
        //Pushbots.customFields({"event_id": data.event_id});
        //Pushbots.customNotificationTitle("CUSTOM TITLE");
        //var token = "APA91bGaZBXL9yv-Gr__0TLju-eMP42oKNPJhTtPocf8ar3OLC736tvi26lcXATDnGw7Ode1B2ONcusTvAP7s2L_06jMo8PIQ1QgmRf9k_EBmn-BqWaZLSK026ZQLWUyoIjArgHF6ssP";
        //Pushbots.pushOne(token, function (response) {
        //  console.log(response);
        //});
    });


});




// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  // print a message when the server starts listening
  console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/rauchg/chat-example I was able to get the following app working in Bluemix. It seems the difference may be calling `http.listen()` vs. `app.listen()`:

index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(process.env.PORT, function(){
  console.log('listening...');
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "socket-chat-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "my first socket.io app",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.10.2",
    "socket.io": "1.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
     "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```